# How to ensure a specific property order in JSON objects using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I have a JSON array containing objects, and I want to ensure that the "id" property is always at the beginning of each object. The order of keys in a JSON object doesn't affect its functionality, but for my use case, I need "id" to be the first in every object. How can I achieve this?

```
const jsonData = [
  {
    "id": 40,
    "front": "Define the concept of a skew-symmetric matrix.",
    "back": "A skew-symmetric (or antisymmetric) matrix is a square matrix whose transpose is equal to its negative. In other words, A matrix A is skew-symmetric if A^T = -A.",
    "lastModified": "2023-12-21T12:30:45.789Z",
    "status": "Want to Learn"
  },
  {
    "front": "front1",
    "back": "back1",
    "lastModified": "2024-01-01T17:44:39.040Z",
    "status": "Want to Learn",
    "id": 41
  }
];
```

This is my function to add new cards:

```
const handleAddCard = async (card) => {
    try {
      const newCard = {
        ...card,
        lastModified: new Date().toISOString(),
      };

      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/flashcards", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(newCard),
      });

      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error("Failed to add card");
      }

      setFlashCards([...flashcards, card]);

      setNewCard(false);

      setCardAdded(true);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error adding card:", error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: If order matters use an _array_, not an object. But it's unclear why you think it does, given you also say you know it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out. I understand that using an array can be a good practice when order matters. In this case, I specifically want to ensure that the "id" property is always at the beginning of each object for readability and consistency.

Comment: JSON does not keep object property order. _"An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs"_ from https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: "*for my use case, I need "id" to be the first in every object*" - what is that use case?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function that places id first using the spread operator. Something like this.

```
function reorderCard(card) {
  const { id, ...rest } = card;
  return { id, ...rest };
}

const handleAddCard = async (card) => {
  try {
    const orderedCard = reorderCard(card);
    // other logic
  } catch (err) {
    //error handling
  }
};
```

Comment: It still adds the id as the last property sometimes

Answer (score 1):

You can just add one liner code to achieve this:

`id: card.id`

whole function will be shown as below

```
     const handleAddCard = async (card) => {
       try {
      const newCard = {
      id: card.id,
         ...card,
          lastModified: new Date().toISOString(),
       };

       const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/flashcards", {
        method: "POST",
         headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
         },
         body: JSON.stringify(newCard),
        });

        if (!res.ok) {
         throw new Error("Failed to add card");
        }

        setFlashCards([...flashcards, card]);

        setNewCard(false);

        setCardAdded(true);
        } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error adding card:", error);
        }
       };
```

Answer (score 0):

"I need "id" to be the first in every object."

Somewhere you have this code

```
for (let prop in obj) {
  // do something with prop, obj[prop]
  // oh no its out of order!
}
```

You could instead use this code

```
let fieldOrder = ["id", "status", "front", "back", "lastModified"];

for (let prop of fieldOrder) {
  // do something with prop, obj[prop]
  // in the order specified by the array above
}
```

You could compute fieldOrder from an object containing unknown properties (that has id)

```
let fieldOrder = ["id", ...Object.keys(obj).filter(k => k !== "id")];
```